# Directional derivative of a probability mass function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions, partial-derivative

Let $X$ be the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with parameters $[p_1,\ldots, p_n]$. Thus $X$ follows a Poisson binomial distribution.

Writing $\mathbf{p}=\left(p_{1}, \ldots, p_{n}\right)$ and $1=(1, \ldots, 1)$, consider the  points $\mathbf{p}$ that lie in the plane $M=\{\mathbf{x}: \mathbf{x} \cdot 1=\mu\}$. i.e., we focus on parameters $\mathbf{p}$ such that $\sum p_i=\mu.$

My goal is to compute the directional derivatives of $P(X=k)$ to show it has a critical point at $\mathbf{p}^{*} =(\mu/n) \textbf{1}$, i.e. for $\mathbf{v} \in 1^{\perp}$,
$$
\partial_{\mathbf{v}} P(X=k)=0
$$.

Can someone help me in finding this critical point?

Comment: $k$ is fixed here right? Are you saying the result holds for each $k$?

Comment: @angryavian, I am saying the result holds for any value of $k$ where $0 \leq k \leq n$.